# Simple PHP MySQL question: what login should I use?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hey guys, I'm just starting out with MySQL and PHP and have a question.

So I went to PHPmyAdmin and created a database. In that data base i created a Table.

Now I want to access the table with PHP and i use the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username_of_my_database","password_of_my_database");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

However, I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user
>   'username_of_my_database'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in
>   /home/user_of_my_database/public_html/mywebsite.com/facebook/home.php
>   on line 3 Could not connect: Access
>   denied for user
>   'username_of_my_database'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

So the log in data are wrong. My question is: **How do you get the right log in data? What do i have to fill in instead of what i did?**

Thanks a lot for your help!

**So what should i use: My username is:  javaaa, my database is called: new year, which make for javaaa_newyear? and the password was made when making the new year database. And within the new year database there is a table called: party.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the parameters must be incorrect.

Remember that ideally your webserver and database should be on *different* servers. If this is the case then "localhost" will not be the correct host for your database and this will mean that you are logging into the **wrong** database - try to find out the correct IP address or hostname for your *database* server (not your *web* server) and use that instead.

If the hostname is correct then it must be an incorrect user name or password.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How can is see in phpMyAdmin which thing to use?

Comment: @Javaaaa: If you type "localhost" to connect to your database from phpMyAdmin then the host that phpMyAdmin is running on is your database server and you should use that host name / IP address when connecting from PHP, and *not* localhost.

Comment: Ok where do i type this? I made a screenshot of my database in PhpMyAdmin maybe you can ubtract from that what to use?

Comment: Ah never mind i think i got it. I went to the MySQl thing in Cpanel and found it, works now! Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

OR

You can create a new user with password in phpmyadmin and can assign this user to access the database.

and then can use the newly created username and passowrd

Comment: Yes i did create a new database with pasword, however it doesnt work. I think the localhost is wrong, is that possible?

Comment: yes then your database is not on the same server. find out the database server ip and replace with localhost as Mark suggested

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How can is see in phpMyAdmin which thing to use?

Comment: @ Shakti: where can i find this database server ip in myphpadmin?

Comment: Ah never mind i think i got it. I went to the MySQl thing in Cpanel and found it, works now! Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: hey you can also get the hostname by executing this query in phpmyadmin SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname';

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a proper mysql db account, or have a typo, if you don't know how to create an account **DON'T USER ROOT CREDENTIALS!**, do the following:

1. Log into **PhpMyAmin**
2. Go to **Privilages**
3. Click **[Add new User]** button
4. Create new user, paying attention to the following field: *host* that defines what location (host machine) it can connect from), if the mysql DB is on the same server as your php script, use *localhost*, otherwise define *any host*.
5. After creating your new user, on the bottom select the database they have access to under **Database-specific privileges**.  It is **NOT** wise to use root/"empty password" as your scripts method of authentication.

Always write down your username and password into your configuration file (or script file that holds the username / passsword for your database).  This will let you test the connection right away with the new credentials.  Pay attention to what database permissions you assign to the user (SELECT / DELETE / INSERT / UPDATE should be minimum, IMHO).

Experiment a little, the rule of thumb is, ONLY give your user account as much permission as it requires, giving any mysql account 'root' permissions is ultimately dangerous, always minimize the impact by minimizing the user permissions.

Comment: ah when i created it, i gave all permissions. Where can i remove those permission as you advise?